# Internet Connection Check phonegap

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am running this piece of code in my phonegap app.
The code is executing perfectly no error,but there is one problem,
whenever it it always shows UNKNOWN CONNECTION, either i run the application on device or emulator,Why is it happening why network type is always unknown.

```
function checkConnection() {
 var networkState = navigator.connection.type;
    var states = {};
    states[navigator.connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown Connection';
    states[navigator.connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
    states[navigator.connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
    states[navigator.connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
    states[navigator.connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
    states[navigator.connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
    states[navigator.connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

    alert('Connection type: ' + states[networkState]);
}
checkConnection();
```

Comment: R u calling this checkconnection after device ready event or before  ?

Answer (score 0):

No error in your code.Have you called checkConnection() method onDeviceReady().Also please check this [link](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_connection_connection.md.html)
.Set your network state as;

```
var networkState = navigator.network.connection.type;
```

Please try this.

```
function checkConnection() {
var networkState = navigator.network.connection.type;

var states = {};
states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

alert('Connection type: ' + states[networkState]);
}
 checkConnection();
```

Also Please check have you added the Permissions needed for different platforms.

Comment: I already mentioned that there is no error in code but problem is,either my wifi is on or off or my data plan is on or off,it always shows UNKNONW CONNECTION....why it doesnt recognize my wifi or any other internet connection..
and YES i had added the permissions.

Comment: And add this line in config.xml  
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network"/>

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same problem changing the feature configuration in "config.xml". If you're trying in Android device, Instead

```
<feature name="NetworkStatus">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.NetworkManager" />
</feature>
```

Try with

```
<feature name="NetworkStatus">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.networkinformation.NetworkManager" />
</feature>
```

(add "**networkinformation.**" before "NetworkManager")

Answer (score 0):

[This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26046959/2831089) works for me.

In the documentation of cordova-plugin you must to ensure that you are viewing the correct version of cordova.
Example: For [Cordova 2.5.0](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.5.0/cordova_connection_connection.md.html#Connection)

```
<plugin name="NetworkStatus" value="org.apache.cordova.NetworkManager" />
```

For [Cordova 3.3.0](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/cordova_connection_connection.md.html#Connection):

```
<feature name="NetworkStatus">
  <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.networkinformation.NetworkManager" />
</feature>
```

Comment: Thanks for these additional info but I think your answer should rather be a comment. As stated you don't have the reputation to comment yet, so don't hesitate to come back when you have it ;)